# How do I retrieve a list of data for each revision in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, api, xmlhttprequest

I have an API endpoint full of different part numbers that stores information on a singular part with all its information. Most parts have multiple revisions as they have been redesigned over time. I am able to pull the information of the part into JSON, but it is only pulling the first revision. For example if I have revision A until D, it only retrieves revision A's Details. I want my code to be able to identify the different revisions and be able to retrieve the revision number with all the information on that specific revision.

I want to be able to select the different available revisions in a Combobox, and once selected I want my textfields to be populated with the revisions information.

What I am looking for:

- Identify the amount of revision the part has.
- create a list of information on each revision with the revision being the key.

Below I have made a basic example of what the files look like in the end point.

```
{
  "root": {
    "item": [
      "Private API Address"
    ],
    "value": {
      "item": [
           {
          "CreatedOn": "2017-08-09,
          "Revision": "A",
          "PartDescription": "Wing",
          "PartNumber": "PW023",
          "Predicted Manu Cost": "24000",
            }

            {
          "CreatedOn": "2018-03-02,
          "Revision": "B",
          "PartDescription": "Wing",
          "PartNumber": "PW023",
          "Predicted Manu Cost": "28000",
              
            }

            {
          "CreatedOn": "2019-03-12,
          "Revision": "C",
          "PartDescription": "Wing",
          "PartNumber": "PW023",
          "Predicted Manu Cost": "32000",
            }
          }
        },
```

Below I have the code for retrieving any single nodes information as JSON.

```
            string PartNumberInput = txtPartNumberInput.Text;

            var baseUrl = "API Address";
            var partsApi = "ProdMgmt/Parts?%24filter=(Number%20eq%20'" + PartNumberInput + "')&%24count=false&%24expand=Representations";
            var clientHolder = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            clientHolder.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("Username", "Password");
            var basicRequest = new RestRequest(partsApi, Method.Get);
            var response = await clientHolder.ExecuteAsync<ExampleContainer>(basicRequest);

            string strresponse = response.Content;
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strresponse);
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(bytes, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reader);

            //Getting single value from json
            string strPartDescription = doc.SelectSingleNode("//PartDescription").InnerText;
            txtPartDescription.Text = strPartDescription;
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You response is json not xml.

Comment: @jdweng My apologies for that one, I have made the adjustments. Thanks for the help!